# Can I call static method from Activity if Activity is destroyed?

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin.android, static-methods, activity-lifecycle

In *Xamarin.Android* if an *Activity* gets killed because of low memory can I still call static methods defined in that *Activity* from another *Activity*. For example:

```
public class MyKilledActivity : Activity 
{
  ....
  public static int MyStaticMethod()
  {
    .....
    return someIntValue;
  }
}

public class AnotherActivity : Activity
{
    .....
    int value = MyKilledActivity.MyStaticMethod(); // Would it work if MyKilledActivity is destroyed?
}
```

Comment: Yes, and I am assuming `someIntValue` is also static based or is it is derived from static values.

Comment: Maybe just as a hint, there are more suitable ways of handing over values from activity to activity instead of static getters. Intents ie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I call static method from Activity if Activity is destroyed?

Just as SushiHangover said, the answer is Yes.

> In Xamarin.Android if an Activity gets killed because of low memory can I still call static methods defined in that Activity from another Activity?

Please note that **Android doesn't kill single activities, Android kills processes.**

Processes are roughly an app and everything in that app- all the activities, services, application class related to that particular app, in most cases one app equals one process.

That means, that if Android trimmed a process, all the activities (and everything else related to that app) inside it will also die as a result. Android (and in particular, the Android Kernel which is responsible for killing processes when reaching certain memory thresholds) doesn't trim single components within that process/ within that app, it doesn't even know or care that they exist.

So if your app is killed via system because of low memory, then, all your `Activity` will be destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

You can always call a static method on any accessible class at any time.  Just use MyClass.staticMethod().  Note that you can't call deadInstanceOfMyClass.staticMethod() this way if deadInstanceOfMyClass == null.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, assuming `someIntValue` is either static or a hardcoded Integer value.